# Why have the zombies not starved in "Zombieland: Double Tap"?

Tags: zombieland

They are smarter zombies, but I doubt if they are engaged in growing food. Given that they don't eat each other, is it explained how they have survived without eating?

Comment: Do they starve to death in the films?

Comment: in some cases, zombies are no longer human but in zombieland, they have been infected by a mad cow-like illness so still biologically human. same thing in 2 days later.

Comment: Oddly, the official Zombieland Twitter account *asked* precisely this question, but appear to have left it unanswered; https://twitter.com/Zombieland/status/2302663274

Comment: I think you meant "28 days later", in which case I think these 2 are very different. In 28 days later, they are still human and can still die to various fatal injury, but in Zombieland, they barely flinch if you don't hit them on the head (at least from what I recall).

Comment: My "8" key sticks. In both 28 Days Later and Z-Land the disease leaves them human. In Z-Land 2 double tap, the mutated zombies are apparently not completely human so if one needed an explanation of a comedy horror movie perhaps that is it.